# Error while indexing Sentinel 2 data on Open Data Cube

Tags: open-data-cube, indexing

If I have sentinel 2 data:

- which .py file do I have to use to create dataset?
- which .yaml file do I have to use for product?

I took file from these 3 providers (https://earthexplorer.usgs.gov/ , https://glovis.usgs.gov/app and https://scihub.copernicus.eu/dhus/#/home); then, I used "s2peps_prepare.py" because is the only one that worked and I added all of the products that I found. My problem was that when I executed "datacube dataset add" the result was "ERROR No matching Product find for dataset eed8......".

[image]

Could someone help me to find a solution for Sentinel 2 data?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I tried to edit text to clarify my problem. Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For Sentinel-2 indexing into the Open Data Cube, I recommend using the [Element-84 maintained Sentinel-2 COGs](https://registry.opendata.aws/sentinel-2-l2a-cogs/), which are available for free from S3.

There's some [documentation here](https://github.com/opendatacube/datacube-dataset-config/blob/main/sentinel-2-l2a-cogs.md) on how to index the data.

In brief:

```bsh
pip install --extra-index-url="https://packages.dea.ga.gov.au" odc_apps_dc_tools

stac-to-dc \
--catalog-href='https://earth-search.aws.element84.com/v0/' \
--bbox='25,20,35,30' \
--collections='sentinel-s2-l2a-cogs' \
--datetime='2020-01-01/2020-03-31'
```

Comment: Thank you very much Alex! I solved my problem!! I'm very happy!
Do I have to delete my message on slack community? I asked the same thing...

Comment: No, it's fine. You've marked my question as the answer here, so that will help others in the future!